# Why I got Error loading state: Failed to open state file(GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new in GCP. I added bucket

```
gsutil mb -p chris02 gs://chris02-state-bucket
```

When I try to initialize project

```
terraform init

Initializing the backend...
Error loading state: Failed to open state file at gs://chris02-state-bucket/m3/gcs_state/default.tfstate: googleapi: got HTTP response code 403 with body: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>UserProjectAccountProblem</Code><Message>User project billing account not in good standing.</Message><Details>The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent</Details></Error>
```

these are the bucket permissions
[image]

what else should I check?

Comment: is your billing account for the project set up properly?

Comment: @Kaishkugashia How to check that?